# Xorg previous version installation steps required

Tags: xorg

We have got ARM processor board for which we are trying to port ubuntu in it. We have got 12.04-armhf rootfs and 14.04 armhf rootfs. When we using 12.04 armhf rootfs, we are sucessful in getting lxde desktop gui and every thing is working fine.

But when we using 14.04-armhf rootfs, even though we install lxde, we are able to boot to terminal/console only, lxde desktop gui is not coming.

When we are issuing `startx` command, we are getting following error:

> "Segmentation fault at 0x0"
>
> Connection refused.

Since, same kernel(3.14) is working fine with 12.04 armhf rootfs and not with 14.04 rootfs, we are doubting may be Xorg version is creating the problem. So, we are thinking of installing of installing old version of xorg for armhf.

How to install older version of xorg manually from terminal. I tried to do the same (`./configure` is working but make is failing. giving error "no targets for make").

Can anybody give us procedure to install xorg (older version) manually from terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You can get older version of applications from [here](http://archive.ubuntu.com)
for [xorg](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/x/xorg/)